# Iterating over multiple lists in python - flask - jinja2 templates

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am facing an issue in Iterating `for loop` over multiple lists in flask jinja2 template.

My code is something looks like below

```
Type = 'RS'
IDs = ['1001','1002']
msgs = ['Success','Success']
rcs = ['0','1']
return render_template('form_result.html',type=type,IDs=IDs,msgs=msgs,rcs=rcs)
```

I am not sure of coming up with correct template so far,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Response</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Type - {{Type}}!</h1>
    {% for reqID,msg,rc in reqIDs,msgs,rcs %}
    <h1>ID - {{ID}}</h1>
    {% if rc %}
    <h1>Status - {{msg}}!</h1>
    {% else %}
    <h1> Failed </h1>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Output I am trying to get is something like below in html page

```
Type - RS
 ID   - 1001
 Status - Failed

 ID   - 1002
 Status - Success
```

Comment: You need to use [zip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: @KobiK that was my first guess too.... It throws error  
UndefinedError: 'zip' is undefined

Answer (score 50, accepted):

you need `zip()` but it isn't defined in jinja2 templates.

one solution is zipping it **before** `render_template` function is called, like:

view function:

```
return render_template('form_result.html',type=type,reqIDs_msgs_rcs=zip(IDs,msgs,rcs))
```

template:

```
{% for reqID,msg,rc in reqIDs_msgs_rcs %}
<h1>ID - {{ID}}</h1>
{% if rc %}
<h1>Status - {{msg}}!</h1>
{% else %}
<h1> Failed </h1>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

also, you can add `zip` to jinja2 template global, using [`Flask.add_template_x`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.add_template_filter) functions(or [`Flask.template_x`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.template_global) decorators)

```
@app.template_global(name='zip')
def _zip(*args, **kwargs): #to not overwrite builtin zip in globals
    return __builtins__.zip(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I found that  https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html says `__builtins__` is Cpython implementation detail, not portable.  I used `import __builtin__` and `return __builtin__.zip` (no s)

Comment: Can’t you just use `zip` instead of `__builtins__.zip`?

Answer (score 8):

You can also pass in `zip` as a template variable if you are going to use it just once and prefer not to pollute global namespace.

```
return render_template('form_result.html', ..., zip=zip)
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer.   Thank you!