# Nested loop in Jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have data coming as a list/tuple of keys with a list/tuple of values & I need to loop it through and display side by side as Questions -  Answers in a table.

Data as questions_page_data.

```
    {
    (
   'Organisation name', 'Organisation address', 'Type of organisation',
     'Have you delivered projects like this before?', 
     'Upload evidence to support your answer',
     'Your Accountant', 'Responsible person', 
     'Do you have endorsements to support your application?', 
     'Who is endorsing your application?', 
    'Upload evidence to support your answer'
    ):
    (
   'sa', 'sas, asa, as, as', 'Limited Company', True, None, 'as', 'as', False, 
  'weqwe', None
   )
   }
```

Jinja code:

```
  <table>

  {% for questions,answers in questions_page_data.items()%}
   <tbody class="table__body">
       {% if questions %}
       {% for question in questions %}
       {% if answers %}
       {% for answer in answers %}
    <tr class="table__row">

    <td class="table__cell">
        {{question }}
    </td>
   
    <td class="table__cell">
    {{answer}}
      </td>

    </tr>
    {%endfor%}
  {%endif%}
  {%endfor%}
  {%endif%}

  </tbody>

  {% endfor %}
   </table>
```

I know that Jinja code is not correct at all :). This is how it should appear. Please advice

```
  Question                   Answer
  Organisation name          sa
```

Comment: Would iterating over multiple lists solve your problem? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306134/iterating-over-multiple-lists-in-python-flask-jinja2-templates) post for more details.

Comment: I cannot zip the list of keys as it has duplicate key name which are required so the option I see is to loop it through in jinja

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. "Upload evidence to support your answer" is twice in a tuple. If I zip it, one of them will be removed. Hope it answers the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something similar to this in your python code:

```
@app.route('/')
def a_route():
    questions_page_data = {
        (
       'Organisation name', 'Organisation address', 'Type of organisation',
         'Have you delivered projects like this before?', 
         'Upload evidence to support your answer',
         'Your Accountant', 'Responsible person', 
         'Do you have endorsements to support your application?', 
         'Who is endorsing your application?', 
        'Upload evidence to support your answer'
        ):
        (
       'sa', 'sas, asa, as, as', 'Limited Company', True, None, 'as', 'as', False, 
      'weqwe', None
       )
      }

    return render_template('a_html_file.html', questions_page_data=questions_page_data, zip=zip)
```

And then in your HTML template you can use `zip` to iterate over your two lists at once:

```
<table>
  {% for questions, answers in questions_page_data.items() %}
    <tbody class="table__body">
      {% if questions %}
        {% for question, answer in zip(questions,answers) %}
            <tr class="table__row">

            <td class="table__cell">
            {{ question }}
            </td>

            <td class="table__cell">
            {{ answer }}
            </td>

            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    </tbody>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

And finally, the result for me looks like this:
[image: data result]